# How can I make an external microphone work with a splitter cable on a laptop with a unified audio jack?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, microphone

I have an HP Pavilion x360 laptop, with Windows 10 installed. I bought an external microphone that plugs into an audio jack, but discovered that the HP Pavilion's unified audio jack for combination headphone/mic headsets doesn't work with devices that are just microphones. After researching online, I discovered that you can use a splitter cable with it to plug in headphones and a mic, but after purchasing a splitter cable, my computer still didn't register the microphone (although it did register the headphones plugged into the other half of the splitter cable).

How can I get my computer to recognize the microphone?

Comment: Does your splitter at least have 4 contacts (tip/ring/ring/sleeve) on the plug?

Comment: @grawity Yes, it does have 4 contacts.